# Inserting linked list at the end

Tags: c

here is my linkedlistcode for inserting node at the end. i am getting the error code dumped. so please help me what is the wrong with the code.

if I keep return; at the end and at the line after *headRef = newnode; its working. so why to return for a void function.

```
struct node
{
    int data; // node format
    struct node* next;
};

void insertAtEnd(struct node** headRef, int newData)
{
    struct node* ptr;
    struct node* newnode;
    ptr = (*headRef);
    newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data = newData;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (*headRef == NULL)
    {
        *headRef = newnode;
    }
    while (ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = newnode;
}
```

Comment: How does python related to that?

Comment: Choose one language

Comment: To diagnose core dumps we need to see a complete program.

Comment: You should set `ptr = *headRef` before entering the `while` loop. Also you should `return` in case `*hreadRef == NULL` so you don't enter the following while loop.

Comment: 1) Check if `malloc` is successful, 2) in case head is NULL do not execute the while loop and rest of the code in `insertAtEnd()`

Comment: tried it before only but no result

Comment: *i am getting the error code dumped*.... what does this mean? If you see an error message and/or error code, please show exactly what it is. You haven't even said whether it's a compilation error or run-time error. Also show how you called your `insertAtEnd` function.

Comment: if i keep return; at the end and at the line after *headRef = newnode; its working. so why to return for a void function

Comment: @ManiTheja, You can easily avoid `return` and just put the code starting from the `while` loop in the `else` block of `if (*headRef == NULL)`

Comment: @kuroThank you so much its working. could u please tell me why it is not working if don't use return statement without else as there are only 2 conditions means that else is not required

Comment: If you do not use `else` or `return`, `ptr` holds the value privously `*headRef` was holding. In case when the list is empty and `*head` is NULL, in while loop you are accessing `ptr->next`. It means code is trying to access `next` element from a NULL pointer and that is why the core dump occured

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have to return inside if because after if statement it again comes into while loop and add extra node at the end

```
struct node
{
    int data; // node format
    struct node* next;
};

void insertAtEnd(struct node** headRef, int newData)
{
    struct node* ptr;
    struct node* newnode;
    ptr = (*headRef);
    newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data = newData;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if (*headRef == NULL)
    {
        *headRef = newnode;
         return;

    }
    while (ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr->next = newnode;
    return;
}
```